# Logback Extensions - Spring Integration - FileAppender not working

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback

Similar to Log4J Spring integration there is a [Logback Spring integration available here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring).

Everything is working fine as documented - as long as I use a `ConsoleAppender`. But configuring a `RollingFileAppender` as spring bean and register it in the *logback.xml* as described is doing nothing. No error, no log file.

Here is the **logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.DelegatingLogbackAppender" />
    <appender name="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.DelegatingLogbackAppender" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO" />
</configuration>
```

Here the **spring-context.xml** part for registration (only the `fileAppender`, the other one is working fine):

```
<!-- Logback Spring Initialization -->
    <bean class="ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.ApplicationContextHolder" />
     <bean id="fileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
            <property name="context" value="#{ T(org.slf4j.LoggerFactory).getILoggerFactory() }" />
            <property name="file" value="/logs/testlog.log"/>
            <property name="append" value="true"/>
            <property name="encoder">
                <bean class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
                    <property name="context" value="#{ T(org.slf4j.LoggerFactory).getILoggerFactory() }" />
                    <property name="pattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

As someone experience with this configuration and point out, what might be helpful or what is missing?

Versions from pom.xml:

```
<spring.version>4.0.9.RELEASE</spring.version>   
<slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
<logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
<logback-extensions.version>0.1.1</logback-extensions.version>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me, what version of spring core, slf4j-api, logback-classic you are using

Comment: @AshokNanda: Added version info. Thanks for reviewing.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `RollingAppender` is missing `TriggeringPolicy` and/or `RollingPolicy` configuration.

To see error/warning messages due to misconfiguration, turn on `debug` mode in `logback.xml`:

```
<configuration debug="true">
  ...
</configuration>
```